# How to connect to ubuntu repositories from ubuntu server 18.04.3 lts in Vbox

Tags: apt, server, 18.04, package-management, update-manager

There was a problem connecting to the repositories with ubuntu. Both systems (host (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)) and the virtual machine with the ubuntu-server 18.04.3 cannot connect to the repositories.
[first try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7aiU.png)
[second try, after editing resolvconf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJbkX.png)
There is an Internet connection, ping on 8.8.8.8 goes

source list:

```
~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
# deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
```

**The next day everything worked, maybe there was some problem with the repository servers**

Comment: Do you have any connection issue ? can you ping google ? My main though is that you would be behind a proxy at work.

Comment: No connectivity issues. ping on 8.8.8.8 is. This is a home computer. I did not configure the proxy, I do not think that it is by default